Efficient Isar Database Backup and Multi-Device Sync (Similar to WhatsApp) in flutter
I'm building a flutter app with Isar for data storage.  I want to back it up to Google Drive and keep it synced across multiple devices, just like WhatsApp does with messages.
The problem: I need a way to efficiently:

Backup the Isar database to Google Drive.
Synchronize the database across devices in real-time or near real-time.
Handle potential conflicts when users edit data on different devices simultaneously. (Optional)
Optimize performance for large databases or frequent updates. (Optional)
Maintain some level of offline functionality while syncing. (Optional)

My goal:  Implement a robust solution to ensure data consistency and a seamless user experience across devices.
**Looking for: **Best practices, libraries, coode snippets and advice on achieving this functionality with Isar and Google Drive.

My suspicion is that the basic Google drive sync will run into too many conflicts on multiple updates to be useful.  You really need more like CRDTs that can have well-resolved eventual consistency.

To backup the Isar database to Google Drive, you can have a look at this tutorial: https://youtu.be/su-h6mdqmBE?si=msCwsPR-W94XfB3Y
